# I don't have a .Xauthority file?

Tags: xorg, login, vnc

I'm trying to license VNC Connect and, after I click "Apply" it says,

```
Failed to run /usr/bin/vnclicensewiz '-helper' '-hash' '73eeed08b449e995f0c7c141551a268ef12b0b077c5eae11c8036e25b4f72c33' '-fork' '/tmp/.vnc-1000/vnclicensewiz.vncpipehelper.190001747' '-log=*:stderr:10' as user root.

Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.
```

I have had the last line appear when I try to do other things, too. I looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40320/unable-to-copy-the-users-xauthorization-file) question but none of the answers worked.

The output of `ls -la ~/.Xauthority` is

```
ls: cannot access '/home/amolith/.Xauthority': No such file or directory
```

The output of `ls -l /home/amolith/*thority`is

```
ls: cannot access '/home/amolith/*thority': No such file or directory
```

The output of `ls -al /home/` is

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Jul 21 09:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root    root    4096 Jul 21 11:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x 27 amolith amolith 4096 Jul 26 08:38 amolith
```

The output of `echo $XAUTHORITY` is blank.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 with GNOME 3 on a Parrot Chromebook. I've never had issues with the .Xauthority file before I did a clean install of Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 from [here on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME).

Comment: What kind of device is this? what Ubuntu version?

Comment: @steeldriver I added the information to the question.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -al /home/`?

Comment: Also, can you post the output of `echo $XAUTHORITY`?

Comment: @Raphael I added the information and am about to look at the question you linked.

Comment: May this be some kind of conflict between the display managers (gdm and lightdm)?

Comment: Is gnome3 on chromebook wayland-based by any chance?

Comment: @steeldriver No. I'm just running straight Ubuntu GNOME on the chrome book so I have the option to boot Wayland like with normal computers but I'm not now. It's just normal Ubuntu GNOME.

Comment: Seems like not a dupe, since we now normally do have an `.Xauthority` file and this is not about 10.10. Even if it turns out that it's somehow normal for OP to have no such file, the explanation for that is a needed part of the answer I think...

Comment: @Zanna What does OP stand for? I've seen a lot of SE users refer to that and I assume it's the person asking the question but I don't know what it stands for and I'm curious, haha.

Comment: :) [there's an SE question for that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean). Do you agree that your Q is not a dupe? You might want to edit it to say so, to prevent it getting closed

Comment: @Zanna Thank you :) I do agree because both the question and answer linked are from 8 years ago and are, in all likelihood, inaccurate due to 8 years of updating. Do I add that to the question?

Comment: The question has 4 close votes. One more will close it, so it's likely to get closed. When/if it gets closed, editing will automatically send it to the reopen queue. If it does get closed and does not get reopened, you can flag it for mod attention (should work) or post on meta (should also work and if it doesn't work you'll get a good explanation at least).

Comment: @Zanna Thank you! I just read your post on Meta regarding Q&A reviewers and wanted to thank you. You put in a lot of (beneficial) work for this website (I see your username everywhere, it seems) and I really admire you for it. :)

Comment: :) :) sorry, it was my bedtime after my last message. Thank you for the kind words!  <3